# Materialize a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What does it mean by materialising a matrix in the field of linear algebra? I cannot find any good explanation so far.

Comment: where did you find this expression?

Comment: did you mean diagonalize?

Comment: I've taught many linear algebra classes at a range of levels, but I've never encountered the phrase "materialize a matrix".  Sometimes the verb "realize" is used in connection with mathematical constructions, so my best guess would be something is meant in connection with representing a linear transformation by a matrix.  But you need to be the expert on what you are asking, so you can clarify your Question for Readers.  Perhaps you can cite a book or paper where this phrase is used?

Comment: I found the phrase in the paper: Yin, X., & Tan, W. (2011, March). Semi-supervised truth discovery. In Proceedings of the 20th international conference on World wide web (pp. 217-226). ACM. First paragraph in Section 5